# Android Studio - Couldn't resize new project Wizard window height

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I am new to both Android and Android Studio.

When I am creating new project in the Android Studio, I am not able to resize the height of the window.

I am facing this problem in both Windows/Linux OS environments.

But in intellij IDEA I am able resize the new project window height.

This is not a problem for me in windows as I am able to see the complete window as below.

[image]

Since my KUbuntu KDE 15.04 Linux environment is installed using VMWare 12, I am not able to see Previous, Next, Cancel and Finish buttons in the bottom.
I have provided the screenshot below -

[image]

Could anybody help me in resizing the height of new project wizard window for Android Studio.